Why is my Azure Functions deploy not working through GitLab CI/CD despite working when done with Azure Function Core Tools extension in VSCode?
I've created some Azure Functions using Python (3.9) and I'm having trouble setting up the CI/CD in the GitLab repository where the code resides. This repository resides in an Azure VM, not sure if that's relevant. The functions connect to an Azure PostgreSQL database, as you will see further down in the code.
The .gitlab-ci.yml triggers 3 jobs: The 2 first ones build and deploy a React app to Azure Static Web Apps successfully. The third one runs successfully in the GitLab pipelines but afterwards i see no functions in the Azure Function App overview page. I also don't see any error logs in the job.
When using the VSCode extension Azure Functions Core Tools to deploy directly to the Azure Function App, the deploy is successful and the functions show in the overview page, and they work correctly, connecting to the database and everything. I'm also able to run and test the functions locally.
Here are the different pieces of code involved. Some information will be ommited for privacy, like URLs
.gitlab-ci.yml:
stages:
  - build-react
  - deploy-react
  - deploy-functions

# Build the React app
build-react:
  stage: build-react
  image: registry.gitlab.com/static-web-apps/azure-static-web-apps-deploy
  script:
    - cd app-frontend
    - npm install
    - VITE_FUNCTIONS_BASE_URL=azurewebsites-url npx vite build
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - app-frontend/dist
  only:
    - main

# Deploy the React app to Azure Static Web Apps
deploy-react:
  stage: deploy-react
  image: registry.gitlab.com/static-web-apps/azure-static-web-apps-deploy
  script:
    - cd app-frontend
    - npm install -g @azure/static-web-apps-cli
    - swa deploy --env production --deployment-token token --output-location ./dist
  only:
    - main

deploy-functions:
  stage: deploy-functions
  image: mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/python:3.0 # Azure Functions image
  script:
    - set -e
    - cd azure_functions  # Navigate to the folder containing your Azure Function app
    - zip -r ../my-functions.zip .  # Create a zip file of only the contents of the azure_functions folder
    - cd ..  # Navigate back to the root directory
    - echo "Zipped successfully"
    - apt-get update && apt-get install -y ca-certificates curl apt-transport-https lsb-release gnupg
    - curl -sL https://aka.ms/InstallAzureCLIDeb | sudo bash
    - echo "Deploying to Azure..."
    - az login --service-principal -u $AZURE_CLIENT_ID -p $AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET --tenant $AZURE_TENANT_ID
    - az functionapp deployment source config-zip --resource-group $AZURE_RESOURCE_GROUP --name $AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_NAME --src ./my-functions.zip
  only:
    - main 


requirements.txt:
azure-functions
psycopg2-binary

function_app.py:
import json
import azure.functions as func
import logging
from datetime import datetime
import psycopg2
import os

# Database connection details
DB_HOST = os.getenv("DB_HOST")
DB_NAME = os.getenv("DB_NAME")
DB_USER = os.getenv("DB_USER")
DB_PASSWORD = os.getenv("DB_PASSWORD")
DB_PORT = os.getenv("DB_PORT")

app = func.FunctionApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)

@app.route(route="desks", methods=["GET"], auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)
def getDesks(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    # Connect to database and fetch reservations for the given date
    try:
        connection = psycopg2.connect(
            host=DB_HOST,
            port=DB_PORT,
            database=DB_NAME,
            user=DB_USER,
            password=DB_PASSWORD,
        )

        cursor = connection.cursor()

        # Query to get all desks
        query = """
        SELECT d.id
        FROM desks d;
        """

        cursor.execute(query)
        desks = cursor.fetchall()

        # Prepare the response data
        if desks:
            response_data = [{"id": desk[0]} for desk in desks]
            return func.HttpResponse(
                body=json.dumps(response_data),
                status_code=200,
                mimetype="application/json",
            )
        else:
            return func.HttpResponse("No desks found", status_code=200)

    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Error fetching desks: {str(e)}")
        return func.HttpResponse(
            "An error occurred while processing the request.", status_code=500
        )
    finally:
        if cursor:
            cursor.close()
        if connection:
            connection.close()


@app.route(route="reservations", methods=["GET"], auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)
def getReservationsForDate(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    # Get the date from the query parameter (expected format: YYYY-MM-DD)
    reservation_date = req.params.get("date")
    if not reservation_date:
        return func.HttpResponse(
            "Please provide a 'date' query parameter (YYYY-MM-DD).", status_code=400
        )

    try:
        # Convert string date to a date object for validation
        reservation_date = datetime.strptime(reservation_date, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
    except ValueError:
        return func.HttpResponse(
            "Invalid date format. Please provide a valid date in YYYY-MM-DD format.",
            status_code=400,
        )

    # Connect to database and fetch reservations for the given date
    try:
        connection = psycopg2.connect(
            host=DB_HOST,
            port=DB_PORT,
            database=DB_NAME,
            user=DB_USER,
            password=DB_PASSWORD,
        )

        cursor = connection.cursor()

        # Query to get all reservations for the provided date
        query = """
        SELECT r.id, r.desk_id, r.reserved_by, r.reservation_date
        FROM reservations r
        WHERE r.reservation_date = %s;
        """

        cursor.execute(query, (reservation_date,))
        reservations = cursor.fetchall()

        # Prepare the response data
        if reservations:
            response_data = [
                {
                    "id": res[0],
                    "desk_id": res[1],
                    "reserved_by": res[2],
                    "reservation_date": res[3].strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),
                }
                for res in reservations
            ]
            return func.HttpResponse(
                body=json.dumps(response_data),
                status_code=200,
                mimetype="application/json",
            )
        else:
            return func.HttpResponse(body=json.dumps([]), status_code=200)

    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Error fetching reservations: {str(e)}")
        return func.HttpResponse(
            "An error occurred while processing the request.", status_code=500
        )
    finally:
        if cursor:
            cursor.close()
        if connection:
            connection.close()


@app.route(
    route="reservation-dates", methods=["GET"], auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS
)
def getDatesWithReservationForEmail(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    email = req.params.get("email")
    if not email:
        return func.HttpResponse(
            "Please provide an 'email' query parameter.", status_code=400
        )

    todays_date = datetime.today().date()

    # Connect to database and fetch dates in which the email provided has reservations
    try:
        connection = psycopg2.connect(
            host=DB_HOST,
            port=DB_PORT,
            database=DB_NAME,
            user=DB_USER,
            password=DB_PASSWORD,
        )

        cursor = connection.cursor()

        # Query to get all reservations for the provided date
        query = """
        SELECT r.reservation_date
        FROM reservations r
        WHERE r.reserved_by = %s AND r.reservation_date >= %s;
        """

        cursor.execute(query, (email, todays_date))
        reservation_dates = cursor.fetchall()

        # Prepare the response data
        if reservation_dates:
            response_data = [res[0].strftime("%Y-%m-%d") for res in reservation_dates]
            return func.HttpResponse(
                body=json.dumps(response_data),
                status_code=200,
                mimetype="application/json",
            )
        else:
            return func.HttpResponse(body=json.dumps([]), status_code=200)

    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Error fetching reservation dates for email {email}: {str(e)}")
        return func.HttpResponse(
            "An error occurred while processing the request.", status_code=500
        )
    finally:
        if cursor:
            cursor.close()
        if connection:
            connection.close()


@app.route(route="reservations", methods=["POST"], auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)
def reserveDesks(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    # Parse the JSON body
    request_body = req.get_json()
    if not request_body:
        return func.HttpResponse("Invalid or missing JSON body.", status_code=400)

    # Extract `userEmail`
    employee_email = request_body.get("employee")
    # Extract `reservations`
    reservations = request_body.get("reservations", [])

    # Validate presence of required fields
    if not employee_email or not reservations:
        return func.HttpResponse(
            "Missing 'employee' or 'reservations' in the JSON body.",
            status_code=400,
        )

    # Database connection
    try:
        connection = psycopg2.connect(
            host=DB_HOST,
            port=DB_PORT,
            database=DB_NAME,
            user=DB_USER,
            password=DB_PASSWORD,
        )

        cursor = connection.cursor()
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Error connecting to the database: {str(e)}")
        return func.HttpResponse("Database connection failed.", status_code=500)

    # Connect to database and fetch reservations for the given date
    try:
        for reservation in reservations:
            desk_id = reservation.get("desk_id")
            reservation_date = reservation.get("reservation_date")

            if not desk_id or not reservation_date:
                return func.HttpResponse(
                    "Each reservation must include 'deskId' and 'reservationDate'.",
                    status_code=400,
                )

            checkIfSameReservationAlreadyExistsQuery = """
            SELECT r.id, r.desk_id, r.reserved_by, r.reservation_date
            FROM reservations r
            WHERE r.reservation_date = %s AND r.desk_id = %s;
            """
            cursor.execute(
                checkIfSameReservationAlreadyExistsQuery, (reservation_date, desk_id)
            )
            reservations = cursor.fetchall()
            if reservations and len(reservations) > 0:
                response_data = [
                    {
                        "id": res[0],
                        "desk_id": res[1],
                        "reserved_by": res[2],
                        "reservation_date": res[3].strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),
                    }
                    for res in reservations
                ]
                return func.HttpResponse(
                    body=json.dumps(response_data),
                    status_code=409,
                    mimetype="application/json",
                )

            # Insert reservation into the database
            insert_query = """
            INSERT INTO reservations (desk_id, reserved_by, reservation_date)
            VALUES (%s, %s, %s)
            """
            cursor.execute(insert_query, (desk_id, employee_email, reservation_date))

        # Commit the transaction
        connection.commit()

    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Error fetching reservations: {str(e)}")
        return func.HttpResponse(
            "An error occurred while processing the request.", status_code=500
        )
    finally:
        if cursor:
            cursor.close()
        if connection:
            connection.close()

    # Return success response
    return func.HttpResponse(
        f"Successfully created {len(reservations)} reservations for {employee_email}.",
        status_code=201,
    )


@app.route(
    route="reservations", methods=["DELETE"], auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS
)
def cancelReservations(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    # Get reservation_ids from query parameter
    reservation_ids_str = req.params.get("reservation_ids")
    if not reservation_ids_str:
        return func.HttpResponse(
            "Please provide reservation_ids as a query parameter.", status_code=400
        )

    try:
        # Split the reservation_ids and convert them into a list of integers
        reservation_ids = list(map(int, reservation_ids_str.split(",")))

        # Connect to database and delete the reservations
        connection = psycopg2.connect(
            host=DB_HOST,
            port=DB_PORT,
            database=DB_NAME,
            user=DB_USER,
            password=DB_PASSWORD,
        )

        cursor = connection.cursor()

        placeholders = ", ".join("%s" for _ in reservation_ids)
        # Query to delete the reservations by IDs
        query = f"""
        DELETE FROM reservations
        WHERE id IN ({placeholders});
        """
        cursor.execute(query, reservation_ids)
        connection.commit()

        # Check how many rows were deleted
        deleted_rows = cursor.rowcount

        if deleted_rows > 0:
            return func.HttpResponse(
                f"Successfully deleted {deleted_rows} reservation(s).", status_code=200
            )
        else:
            return func.HttpResponse(
                "No reservations found with the provided IDs.", status_code=404
            )

    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Error deleting reservations: {str(e)}")
        return func.HttpResponse(
            "An error occurred while processing the request.", status_code=500
        )

    finally:
        if cursor:
            cursor.close()
        if connection:
            connection.close()



Do you have a React app deployed on Azure Static Web Apps along with an Azure Function? Are you trying to deploy both the Azure Static Web App and the Azure Function? Are they connected, with the Azure Function acting as a backend API for the React app frontend? Do you want the function to serve as your backend API? If so, why are you using Azure CLI for deployment?

@Sampath correct, the functions serve as the backend API to the Static Web App. I'm not sure i understand your final question, I'm using CLI so that the functions are automatically updated when changes are commited to the main branch of the repository

please share you git file link

i can't do that. I've shared the entirety of the file.

Below is an example of a .gitlab-ci.yml file for deploying your project using npm and the Azure Static Web Apps deployment workflow.

Refer to this link for building and deploying React using GitLab CI pipeline.

variables:
  API_TOKEN: $DEPLOYMENT_TOKEN
  APP_PATH: '$CI_PROJECT_DIR'
  OUTPUT_PATH: '$CI_PROJECT_DIR/build'

cache:
  paths:
    - node_modules/
    - .yarn

stages:
  - build
  - deploy

build_job:
  image: node:16
  stage: build
  script:
    - npm install
    - npm run build
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - ./build

deploy_job:
  environment: production
  stage: deploy
  image: mcr.microsoft.com/azure-static-web-apps-deploy:latest
  script:
    - echo "Deploying to Azure Static Web App..."
    - npx azure-static-web-apps-deploy --app-location "/" --api-location "./api" --output-location "build" --token $API_TOKEN


I have changed the app_location to /, api_location to ./api, and output_location to build based on the folder structure. Change these values according to your own folder structure.
Output of react app in Static web app:

Output of Azure Function app api  in Static web app: :**


Alternatively, you can use only a .yml file, such as azure-static-web-apps.yml, with the app_location set to /, api_location set to ./api, and output_location set to build according to the folder structure. Refer to my SO post for more details.
Updated  to deploy to azure function:
updated deployment script with explicit dependency installation:
deploy-functions:
  stage: deploy-functions
  image: mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/python:3.0
  script:
    - set -e
    - cd azure_functions
    - python3 -m venv .ven
    - source .venv/bin/activate 
    - pip install -r requirements.txt 
    - zip -r ../my-functions.zip .  
    - cd ..  
    - echo "Zipped successfully"
    - apt-get update && apt-get install -y ca-certificates curl apt-transport-https lsb-release gnupg
    - curl -sL https://aka.ms/InstallAzureCLIDeb | sudo bash
    - echo "Deploying to Azure..."
    - az login --service-principal -u $AZURE_CLIENT_ID -p $AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET --tenant $AZURE_TENANT_ID
    - az functionapp deployment source config-zip --resource-group $AZURE_RESOURCE_GROUP --name $AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_NAME --src ./my-functions.zip
  only:
    - main


This is not the issue. The deployment of my React app to Azure Static Web Apps works perfectly fine, it is the Azure Functions that have a problem. @Sampath

Updated. if you  want to deploy function app as api use  api_location  as  ./api

thank you for the comments. Unfortunately neither solution worked.

for more deatils Refer to  link  to deploy function app using .gitlab-cli.yml.
